# Running a SSIS package from a SSRS report - SSRS 2014-2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014

I need to launch a SSIS package from a SSRS report. I know that SSRS isn't an input data system, but I need to run interactively a SSIS package, without specifying any input data.
Is it possible a such operation? If possible, I'd like to use a code (Javascript?) inside SSRS to do it.

Thanks

Comment: This is a bad idea fullstop. But here's a clue: an SSRS report can use a stored procedure as a data source. And that stored procedure can call `catalog.start_execution` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15. You certainly can't run it interactively without having SSDT installed but you can query the execution logs. Still.... it's a bad idea

Comment: Jacascript can really only call web services and change the DOM. It can't do anything outside the browser. It definitely can't start an SSIS package but it can call a web service that does.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to run an application from a report there are different approaches:

1. Creating an assembly where you define all functions and add it as reference within the report
2. Using embedded code within the report
3. creating a batch file (.bat) that contains the command and upload it to the reporting server and use its URL when needed.

Concerning SSIS, you can use DTEXEC utlity which is installed with SQL Server to execute dtsx package via command line.

For more information about what I mentioned, you can refer to the following links:

- [How to use custom assemblies or embedded code in Reporting Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920769/how-to-use-custom-assemblies-or-embedded-code-in-reporting-services)
- [Launching an application from Reporting Services](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2be43409-2f31-4c27-a41a-65c213366d3a/launching-an-application-from-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [Execute .exe in SSRS Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577094/execute-exe-in-ssrs-report)
- [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Run an SSIS package from the command prompt with DTExec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-cmdline?view=sql-server-ver15)